# Number of quarters gap to int

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I calculate number of quarters gap between two dates. Now, I want to test if the number of quarters gap is bigger than 2.

Thank you for your comments!

I'm actually running a code from WRDS (Wharton Research Data Services). Below, `fst_vint` is a DataFrame with two date variables, `rdate` and `lag_rdate`. First line seems to convert them to quarter variables (e.g., `9/8/2019` to `2019Q1`), and then take differences between them, storing it in a new column `qtr`.

`fst_vint.qtr >= 2` creates a problem, because the former is a `QuarterEnd` object, while the latter is an `integer`. How do I deal with this problem?

```
fst_vint['qtr'] = (fst_vint['rdate'].dt.to_period('Q')-\
fst_vint['lag_rdate'].dt.to_period('Q'))

# label first_report flag
fst_vint['first_report'] = ((fst_vint.qtr.isnull()) | (fst_vint.qtr>=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using .diff() when column is converted to integer with .astype(int) results in the desired answer. So the code in your case would be:

```
fst_vint['qtr'] = fst_vint['rdate'].astype(int).diff()
```